# Partner not reached error in JCO.destination

Tags: java, jco

I'm Having a problem establishing a connection to SAP in my java program.
I'm following the examples that come in the JCO download but i always get this error:

```
    com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (102) RFC_ERROR_COMMUNICATION: Connect to SAP gateway failed
    Connection parameters: TYPE=A DEST=ABAP_AS_WITHOUT_POOL ASHOST=xx.xx.x.xx SYSNR=00 PCS=1

    LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
    ERROR       partner 'xx.xx.x.xx:3300' not reached

    TIME        Wed Jul 08 08:18:28 2015
    RELEASE     711
    COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
    VERSION     39
    RC          -10
    MODULE      nixxi.cpp
    LINE        3147
    DETAIL      NiPConnect2: xx.xx.x.xx:3300
    SYSTEM CALL connect
    ERRNO       10060
    ERRNO TEXT  WSAETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out
    COUNTER     2
```

I don't know what it can be, i'm writing down the correct connection properties (ashost,user,passwd,sysnr,etc).
Has anybody else has had a problem like this?

This is my connection code:

```
    Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "xx.xx.x.xx");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR,  "00");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "020");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER,   "xxxxxx");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "xxxxxxx");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG,   "en");
    createDataFile(ABAP_AS, "jcoDestination", connectProperties);
```

After that i just instantiate the object with those properties and call the method connect that is written like this:

```
    JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(ABAP_AS);
    System.out.println("Attributes:");
    System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
    System.out.println();
```

I'm working on Java, using netbeans, the sapjco3.jar is added to my libraries.
Do i have to do anything with the dll file that comes?

Comment: Are you sure that there's no networking issue involved? Maybe some firewall is blocking port 3300?

Comment: Already checked. That's why i'm confused.@vwegert

Comment: I was told that maybe i need to connect via saprouter instead of only by the ashost. Do you know how to do this? @vwegert

Comment: Just set the property JestinationDataProvider.JCO_SAPROUTER to the SAProuter string. '/H//H/' is not a valid SAProuter string. To find out what your local network and application server settings might be, you need to talk to your local IT guys, not post in some anonymous forum. This is not an issue with the software, but with your local configuration.